# Why am I getting these error messages?

Tags: adobe, dynamic-linking, after-effects, adobe-cc

I having been working with Adobe After Effects and want to export some comps with Adobe Media Encoder, but when I try to export a comp from After Effects using Media Encoder, I get these error messages:

[Adobe After Effects Error Messages](https://i.stack.imgur.com/riu8Q.png)

I know both programs are installed and are both Adobe CC versions. I have never had this problem before... does anyone know why I am getting these error messages?

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes that happens when you're using for example, a 2015 version of After Effects with a 2017 media encoder.

Try to reinstall the most recent version of the apps, or at least, try reinstalling the Adobe Media Encoder.